# Poisson Process: Expectation of product

Tags: expectation, poisson-distribution

Assume that calls arrive at a call centre according to a Poisson arrival process  with a rate of  15 calls per hour. For $0 ≤ s < t$, let $N(s,t)$ denote the number of calls which arrive between time $s$ and $t$ where time is measured in hours.

What is $E(N(1,4)N(2,6))$?

I am confused by this because I know $E(XY) = E(X) E(Y)$ if X and Y are independent but in this case the periods of time overlap and are not independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the intervals up:

$$N(1,4)=N(1,2)+N(2,4)\qquad\text{ and }\qquad N(2,6)=N(2,4)+N(4,6).$$

So

\begin{eqnarray*}
E(N(1,4)N(2,6)) &=& E([N(1,2)+N(2,4)]\;N(2,6))) \\
&=& E(N(1,2)N(2,6) + N(2,4)\;[N(2,4)+N(4,6)]) \\
&=& E(N(1,2)N(2,6) + N(2,4)^2 + N(2,4)N(4,6)) \\
&=& E(N(1,2))E(N(2,6)) + E(N(2,4)^2) + E(N(2,4))E(N(4,6)) \\
&=& \lambda\cdot 4\lambda + (2\lambda)^2 + 2\lambda + 2\lambda\cdot 2\lambda \\
&&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{since $E(N(s,t)^2)=((t-s)\lambda)^2+(t-s)\lambda$} \\
&=& 12\lambda^2 + 2\lambda \\
&=& 2730 \quad\text{with $\lambda=15$}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: thank you! I have not come across this before.